# Convert CompressionOutputStream to ByteString in scala

Tags: scala, compression, bytearrayoutputstream

There is a JAVA compression API call which gives me **CompressionOutputStream** and I want to return a ByteString. From what I have seen and tried to do is:

1. Using StreamConverters (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/StreamConverters/fromOutputStream.html)
   val sink:

> Sink[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] =
> StreamConverters.fromOutputStream(() => outputStream)  <- This returns
> a Sink but I do not how to convert it to ByteString

2. Using BufferedOutputStream (There is no #getBytes in CompressionInputStream so I wanted to convert it to BufferedOutputStream but its not correct)

> ```
> val bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream()
> bufferedOutputStream.writeTo(myOutputStream)
> bufferedOutputStream.getBytes()
> ```

Any suggestions/help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: The sink you mention is to read bytes and wryte them into an Output stream. Not what you want.

Comment: The link is for reading an InputStream to ByteArray. In this case, I am trying to convert OutputStream to ByteString

Comment: Yes but you can easily construct a ByteString from an array of byte.

Comment: Ah yes, the problem I am stuck is I am not able to convert CompressionOutputStream to ByteArrayOutputStream so I am not able to use  "byte[] responseArray = baos.toByteArray();" directly. CompressionOutputStream does not have #toByteArray

Comment: Is this Hadoop's CompressionStream? If so it wraps an output stream so you should get a hand on the wrapped outputstream.

Comment: It is hadoop's CompressionOutputStream. This makes sense. I tried doing it using this  bufferedOutputStream.writeTo(myOutputStream) but didn't wok